# Why doesn't Ubuntu Gnome work properly in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, gnome, vmware-player

I've tried installing [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) in VirtualBox and VMware Player. In both cases I end up with a weird graphical bug on the desktop. Everything else *seems* to be working as it should, although VirtualBox crashed after a few minutes when I tried using 2 monitors.

I've also tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 normally, following a guide to installing Gnome 3 then logging on using Gnome 3 instead of Unity. The graphical bug still occurs.

[image: Screenshot]

Am I right in assuming that this is a Ubuntu/Gnome 3 issue rather than a VM issue, seeing as this is occurring on two completely separate VM applications? Does anybody know what is happening?

---

*Note:* I've installed Ubuntu with Gnome 3 on my laptop, and it works fine. That's why I'm assuming that this issue is somehow VM related, perhaps through "VMware Tools" or "Guest additions".

Comment: Did you install the Guest additions?